# Updating a specific object in an array

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm writing an SPA in Svelte. Now, I'm fairly new to the concepts of ES6 so I'm having difficulties wrapping my head around some basic concepts.

I have a store:

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

function selectedOptions() {
    const selection = writable([
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Title 1",
            selections: []
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Title 2",
            selections: []
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: "Title 3",
            selections: []
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            title: "Title 4",
            selections: []
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            title: "Title 5",
            selections: []
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            title: "Title 6",
            selections: []
        }
    ]);

    return {
        subscribe: selection.subscribe,
        updateSelection: item => {
            selection.update((items) => {
                //I want to update the object with the same id as the object 
                //I'm passing in to the method.
           });
        };
    }
}
export default selectedOptions();
```

In my component, I want to pass an object and update the corresponding object in my array with provided values:

```
function handleChange(e) {
    selectedOptions.updateSelection({
        id: 1, title: "Title 1", selections: ["Option 1, Option 2"]
    });
}
```

How do I "replace" an existing object with a new one thus triggering an update to all components that are subscribing to the store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the spread syntax to copy all the original keys, then add the one you want to modify:

```
selection.update(items => {
  return {
     ...items,
     [item.id]: item
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the array method [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and merge the new and old object if the `id` matches or just return the old object as-is if the `id` doesn't match.

```js
updateSelection: item => {
  selection.update(items => {
    return items.map(i => (i.id === item.id ? { ...i, ...item } : i));
  });
};
```